# What is the latest/most-stable ZeroMQ C# version?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I've been trying to do some tests using ZeroMQ C# Binding but I've noticed that the C# examples that they have on their guide use a different version (namespaces and classes) from the C# Binding that is available to download on github.

To be more clear, their examples use a version of the context class that is meant to be used with the new operator, new ZMQ.Context(), but the C# Binding on github has ZeroMQ.ZmqContext.Create().

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Stable release 2.1** also

Beta release 3.1 available(**Beta** means its given for user Testing purpose it may not work  at some cases )

**please use stable release 2.1**